# COM-Objects containing maps / content error(0)

Tags: c++, dll, com, maps, wrapper

I'm writing a small wrapper to get familiar with some important topics in C++ (WinAPI, COM, STL,OOP). For now, my class shall be able to create a (child) window. 
Mainly, this window is connected to a global message loop that distribute messages to a local loop of the right instance (global is static, local is virtual).

Obviously, there are surely better ways to do that but I'm using std::maps to store HWND and their instance pointer in pairs (the Global loop looks for the pointer with the HWND-parameter, gets itself the pointer from the map and calls then the local loop).

Now, it appears that the map does not accept any values because of a unknown reason. It seems to allocate enough space but something went wrong anyway [ (error) 0 is displayed instead of the entries in visual C++).

I've looked that up in google as well and found out that maps cause some trouble when used in classes AND DLLs.  May this be the reason and is there any solution??

Protected scope of class: `static std::map<HWND,MAP_BASE_OBJECT*> m_LoopBuf`

Implementation in .cpp-file: `std::map<HWND,MAP_BASE_OBJECT*> HWindow::m_LoopBuf;`

OK, because you asked for more code here you are:

I actually don't import the DLL because I use COM.
`
  HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        int retval = 1; 
        MSG msg = {0};

```
IClassFactory* Class = NULL;
IWindow* Wnd= NULL;

hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_IWindow,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_IWindow,(LPVOID*)&Wnd);

Wnd->CreateOverlappedWindow(L"My window",L"MyClass",250,250,250,250,0,0,0,0,0,hInst);

while (GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)>0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

Wnd->Release();

return hr;
```

The COM-object IWindow is implemented in the class HWindow (in the DLL). The program expample works well until "CreateOverlappedWindow".

Comment: No maps don't cause any problem; neither in classes, nor in DLL's. From your description, it seems that there is no compile time or run time error---only that the values you are getting back are not what you expected to be stored in the map. Can you share some more code?

Comment: Very unclear.  Are you actually using DLLs?  Is everything compiled with the same settings?  Are you using /MD?

Comment: @ Jay Walker: Yes, there actually is no compile error. Originally it even worked with that strange error. I was also able to build a window. The values actually were ok then but only now i'm getting strange results (flickering and  laggs).                                                              @Hans Pasant: Yes I use a DLL-build (COM-Object).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you are using DLLs specifically, I can only speculate that you are using static linking to the C++ runtime library in your DLLs. That means the memory allocated by each DLL is allocated on a heap separate from the main running program. You either have to change the linkage on your DLLs so that there is only one shared copy of the C++ runtime library or create an allocator for the map that is located in a specific location so that the map only uses one runtime library for its allocations.